# KQL Query for SharePoint Online List (Column) Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, kql, kql-query

I am trying to search for two title fields in a SharePoint list using KQL and can't seem to get this to work.  I can get it to work for a single Column, but I can't get it to search for a second column.

In this example it will search the title field, but it will not search the TestName field.

```
Title:({searchTerms}) OR Test_x0020_Name:({searchTerms}){896d37b8-2727-448f-b2eb-135abcdefgdc}
```

- I have removed Title and replaced with Test_x0020_Name and it still will not search.
- I have reindexed the list but this also did not help.
- I also tried adding a new field with a cleaner name "TestName" and that also does not turn up any results.
- Both of these fields are regular text fields

**Is my syntax right for doing a search for one or the other search terms?**

Any pointers on where to go for more information would also be appreciated, don't mind doing the research.

Comment: Did you create managed properties for your list columns & mapped with corresponding crawled properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using list column, you need to map the related crawled property to built in managed property(or create a new managed property)in search schema:

[image]
After mapping it to a valid built in managed property,wait for a while,or you could create a site column and add it to your library,fill in values, SharePoint will creat the managed property automatically.
[image]

Simple test result:
[image]
Similar issue for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/408476/how-to-filter-sharepoint-online-queries-kql-docume.html